# PyOTRS connection to the remote server is aborted by the remote end

Tags: python, otrs

I'm trying to use PyOTRS lib to work with OTRS community edition API, but there is an error at session_create step:

```
client = Client(baseurl="host_ip", username="username", password="passwd",)
client.session_create()
```

And the error is:

> Error with http communication: ('Connection aborted.',
>   RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)

Comment: What is your baseurl? It could maybe be that it is not accepting connections.

Comment: BaseUrl is simply ip address, where OTRS 6.0 placed, besides, there is `webservice_path` argument with "/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl/Webservice/GenericTicketConnectorREST/Session" as default value while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english. Actually for OTRS 5.x.x
they don’t write anywhere in the pyOTRS manual that a web service needs to be configured before use.
name must be GenericTicketConnectorREST
Add Session, TicketCreate, TicketGet, and TicketUpdate operations.
Click "Configure" next to HTTP: REST and then specify route maps as on the screen.
[Route Map to functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2TyV.png)